# Error, While Sending mail through nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am working on Registration system, I have to authenticate user by sending email using nodemailer. But I am getting error, attached in image. Below is my code.

[image: Attached Image of Error]

Please Help to find where i am wrong. Thanks In Advance.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
   user: 'email',
   pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'email in 6th line',
  to: 'test@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'Tried first time to send email using node js!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
   console.log(error);
  } else {
   console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy installed on your network?

Comment: Are you setting up actual email and password in the following block auth: {
   user: 'email',
   pass: 'password'
  }
if yes  please go to gmail setting section and check  "Allow less secure apps" option and try again, it should probably work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to Both of You, Specially @DineshNagar . It is working now,  Can you Please tell me, Why I need to Allow Less Secure Apps.

Comment: @Rajat, untill unless you dont have ssl certificate (https) or other security parameters for a web app implemented you will need to check the option "Allow less secure app" , to bypass all of this I would suggest you to use sendgrid node module. Although it is a paid third  party service , but it works like a charm , Also if my earlier comment helped you to solve your problem you can upvote that. Thanks :)